# Array problems in for loop

Tags: python

I want to go from one array A of 10 elements to the array B of 100 elements.

Each element of B from 0 to 9 is equal to the element 0 of A

Each element of B from 10 to 19 is equal to the element 1 of A

....

Each element of B from 90 to 99 is equal to the element 9 of A

I did the following code but it does not work

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
A = np.asarray(a)

b = []
for i in range(len(A)*10):
    b.append(0)
    
B = np.asarray(b)   

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(9):
        B[j]=A[i]
```

Expected result:

```
B [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
  ...,
  9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 ]
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Have a look at the `numpy.repeat` function; [docs here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

Comment: Best answer thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving values only in first 9 list elements. You have to 'scale' it by adding `i*10` to index.

```
import numpy as np

a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A = np.asarray(a)

b = []
for i in range(len(A)**2):
    b.append(0)
    
B = np.asarray(b)   

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        B[j + i*len(A)]=A[i]

print(B)
```

Comment: Actually by using a nother vector as A I obtain every 9 value a 0. I cannot understand why

Comment: I edited my answer so it can be more scalable. I hope it will work now

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> [ x for i in a for x in [i]*3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>>
```

You may replace `3` with `10` or whatever you like.

---

Answering the question from Jacob:

```
>>> [[a]*10 for a in A]
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: The double for loop seems a bit over kill (harder to understand) when you can instead use `[[a]*10 for a in A]`

Comment: @JakobVinkas you'll get list of lists, not a simple list from your code. try running it in python

Comment: Oh you are correct, I wrote my answer before the question was edited to clearly display the structure of the B array, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid loops with numpy whenever possible. It kind of defeats the point. Here you can just use [`repeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np

a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
A = np.asarray(a)
B = A.repeat(10)
```

B:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
       6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
       8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9])
```

If want the a nested list, just reshape:

```
B = A.repeat(10).reshape(-1, 10)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy and specify how many iterations of each element you want:

```
import numpy as np
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [np.full(10, a) for a in A]
print(B)
```

Or if you prefer to not use numpy, instead use:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [[a]*10 for a in A]
print(B)
```

Giving you the wanted list B

Comment: My answer is not the best one, but in this case `a` referes to `a in A` making such that `a` will take iterating values (all of the values) of `A` from start to end of the array

Comment: Ok I understood it is the element of the array. But, now I get the following results: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]] Is it possible to compact everything in one array? In this way: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = []
for x in a:
    b += [x] * 10
print b
```

This answer is better, idea from [lenik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329296/lenik)

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [x for x in a for i in range(10)]
print b
```

Comment: Hi, how would be possible to avoid the double square brakets?

Comment: I don't think it can avoid.

Comment: The answer  `[x for i in a for x in [i] * 10]` from `lenik` is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [*range(10)]
b = []
for i in range(10):
    b.extend([a[i]* 10])
B = np.asarray(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` were a generic list and not an ordered sequence

```
In [20]: a = [1, 'a', 3.14159, False, {1:2, 3:4}]
```

you could do as follows

```
In [21]: [_ for _ in (zip(*(a for _ in a))) for _ in _]
Out[21]: 
[1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 'a',
 'a',
 'a',
 'a',
 'a',
 3.14159,
 3.14159,
 3.14159,
 3.14159,
 3.14159,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 {1: 2, 3: 4},
 {1: 2, 3: 4},
 {1: 2, 3: 4},
 {1: 2, 3: 4},
 {1: 2, 3: 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in a single line: `print([item for sublist in [[i]*10 for i in range(1,10)] for item in sublist])`

Answer (score -1):

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in range (0,10,1):
    list1.append(i)
print(list1)
for i in range (0,10,1):
    for j in range (0,10,1):
        j=i
        list2.append(j)
print(list2)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations.